# Confused on Babel.config.js (multiple presets)

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I am trying to implement vue-test-utils with jest to my project.

My question is about my babel.config.js (.babelrc)

I need to set my `babel.config.js` like below as vue-test-utils documentation said,

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "env",
      { modules: false }
    ]
  ],  
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [["env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]]
    }
  }
}
```

`npm test` working without problem but `vue-cli-service serve` command crushes.
[image: cli-error]

With `babel.config.js` by default on vue-cli-3

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@vue/app"
  ]
}
```

In this case, `vue-cli-service serve` working properly but `npm test` crushes.
[image: test-error]

I am newbie on babel things. Any suggestion ?

Comment: This looks to be related to your issue. github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879 The solutions near the bottom of the thread look to be the best. - I deleted my answer as it's not relevant.